# Change confidence interval values in qplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I run this command:

```
qplot(X, Y, data=Datos, geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="lm", formula= y ~ poly(x, 2))
```

I assume that confidence interval shadow I obtain is 95%, as I checked manually. However, how could I change its value, for example, to 90% in that code?

Comment: you can set the level in geom_smooth(); check this: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_smooth.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `level` parameter as Henk said, like this

```
qplot(x= qsec, y=wt, data=mtcars, geom=c('point', 'smooth'), 
method='lm', formula = y~poly(x, 2) , level = 0.7)
```